# High loss despite high accuracy?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I'm running Keras on a binary classification problem using binary cross entropy as my loss function. I can get my accuracy on my train data up to 90% but it still reports a high loss 7 or more. How can this be the case? should loss always be aiming to be close to zero?

Comment: Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258166/good-accuracy-despite-high-loss-value

Comment: thank you, that's mean sometimes high Loss doesn't refer to a problem!